# recover email from imap account using mailx

Tags: authentication, imap, mailx

I am having problems fetching emails with mailx. My imap account uses ssl/tls connection with normal password authentication on port 993. I don't have any problems sending through smtp though. Here is my ~/.mailrc:

```
set verbose
account bell {
set smtp-use-starttls
set smtp=smtp://smtp-mail.outlook.com:587
set smtp-auth=login
set smtp-auth-user=$USERNAME@bell.net
set smtp-auth-password=$PASSWORD
set from="$NAME <$USERNAME@bell.net>"
set nss-config-dir=/etc/openldap/certs
set ssl-verify=ignore

set folder=imaps://$USERNAME@imap-mail.outlook.com:993/INBOX
}
```

Mailx prompts for my password, then responds with "invalid username or password".
Here is the output of "mail -A bell":

```
Resolving host imap-mail.outlook.com . . . done.
Connecting to 157.56.195.250 . . . connected.
Comparing DNS name: "*.hotmail.com"
Comparing DNS name: "*.live.com"
Comparing DNS name: "*.outlook.com"
SSL parameters: cipher=AES-256, keysize=256, secretkeysize=256,
issuer=CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - G2,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,C=BE
subject=CN=*.hotmail.com,O=Microsoft Corporation,L=Redmond,ST=Washington,C=US
* OK Outlook.com IMAP4rev1 server version 17.4.0.0 ready (DUB451-IMAP167)
>>> T1 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN ID NAMESPACE UIDPLUS UNSELECT AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR
T1 OK CAPABILITY completed
Password:
>>> T2 LOGIN "$USERNAME" "$PASSWORD"
T2 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid username or password.
IMAP error: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid username or password.
Password:
```

Is this related to the authentification method or am I missing some ssl/tls config options?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing whole section for IMAP server. Since they are using outlook it should work similar to Hotmail

```
account hotmail {
    set MAIL=imaps://username%40hotmail.com@imap-mail.outlook.com
    set imap-use-starttls
    set password-username%40hotmail.com@imap-mail.outlook.com="secret"
    set smtp="smtp-mail.outlook.com:587"
    set from="My Name <username@hotmail.com>"
    set smtp-use-starttls
    set smtp-auth="login"
    set smtp-auth-user=username@hotmail.com
    set smtp-auth-password="secret"
    }
```

I didn't make mistake using %40 instead of @. The latest s-nail (Linux mailx is much behind) doesn't like two @ since which Microsoft uses.